# Link URL not opening when given in HYPERLINK but opening when pasting the url directly in address bar

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, hyperlink

I have found some url's which i want to hyperlink from my website but when i added hyperlink for those url's then the page is not opening but when i directly paste that url in address bar and enter then it is opening . . .

Example url is http://google.co.in

```
<h6 style="text-align: center;"><strong> <a href="http://google.co.in" target="_blank"> <strong>LINK1</strong></a></strong></h6>
```

please help me in this

thankyou

Comment: and what does your link look like?

Comment: Wrtie some code... We want some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, that the sites check the [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

If you open the link in a window and paste the URL, the referer is empty. If you click on a link, the URL of the site containing the link will be in the referer.

Comment: can u please tell me how to hyperlink now ?? pls

Comment: Just use anonym.to: http://anonym.to?http://jntuconnect.net/results/results/E19v2NcumXmDsIg0N8n_CJpvyRM4EVfo0JD32jg_KnBFPShQGtw0smXRwTBAl3-SMKw1CTD8GWaVes3_8M85JA

Answer (score 1):

The server is configured to not respond to requests where the referrers are from an external site.

So it will respond only if:

1. You have no referrer (which is the case when you enter the URL yourself in the browser's URL bar)
2. Your referrer is that website only (which is the case if you click that link from that website itself)

Comment: is there any alternative way so that i can hyperlink it . .  ??

Comment: Sorry, you can't. The referer can be spoofed only from the browser, not by any website.

Your best bet would be to link to the home page of that website and then mention in the text for the users to click the correct link from there.